# Java + Eclipse + Pulpcore

Tags: java, eclipse, pulpcore

I've never programmed in java or eclipse before, although I have used c# and visual studio.

I'm trying to get started with java development, and develop 2d games, but I can't get the project to run. I've followed the tutorial here:
http://cloningtheclassics.com/getting-started-with-pulpcore/
I've retried the tutorial at least 5 times, and I still can't get it to work.

```
The error it displays is:

Buildfile: C:\workspace\javapulp\project\build.xml
  [taskdef] Could not load definitions from resource tasks.properties. It could not be found.
  [taskdef] Could not load definitions from resource tasks.properties. It could not be found.
-init:

BUILD FAILED
C:\workspace\javapulp\project\build.xml:127: Required file not found: ../../build/pulpcore-applet-debug-0.11.jar

Total time: 1 second
```

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: I found http://groups.google.com/group/pulpcore/web/pulpcore-templates-build-xml-eric-berry
how do I run this? What do I do with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- The first issue is your `tasks.properties` file which is not found.
- The second issue is about `../../build/pulpcore-applet-debug-0.11.jar`, and `pulpcore-applet-debug-0.11.jar` [should be copied in](http://cloningtheclassics.com/getting-started-with-pulpcore/java-build-path/) `c:\workspace\library\pulpcore 0.11.3`" directory.
  (That is the key section for you to double-check).
  That (`c:\workspace\library\pulpcore 0.11.3`) is the `pulpcore.path` property in the `build.xml` file.

Those two issues tend to indicate you did follow the [ant configuration section](http://cloningtheclassics.com/getting-started-with-pulpcore/ant-configuration/) by selecting a `build.xml` under the template\project folder, and then try to configure it.
I would recommend replacing it by the **[sample `build.xml`](http://cloningtheclassics.com/wp-content/uploads/2008/05/build.xml)** mentioned in the same page, double-check the paths and see if that `build.xml` file works better.

Comment: my pulpcore path is C:\workspace\library\pulpcore-0.11.5
do I need to change it or can I edit the build.xml to recognize where it is?

Comment: Okay, I edited it to C:\workspace\library\pulpcore-0.11.5\build
now the error is

Buildfile: C:\workspace\javapulp\project\build.xml
-init:

BUILD FAILED
C:\workspace\javapulp\project\build.xml:204: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\workspace\javapulp\project\src\ProjectBuild.java (The system cannot find the path specified)

Total time: 1 second

Comment: @cable729: that is the difficulty of using the sample `build.xml` provided in the tutorial: the paths need to be adjusted to your environment.

Comment: why is eclipse so hard to set up? visual studio has easy templates and none of this messiness, but this is ridiculous. Is there no easier way?

Comment: @cable729 Once you get comfortable with eclipse, you will love it for the flexibility it gives. Though I agree, VS Studio is really good.